# Eigen + MKL sparse matrix

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, intel-mkl

I just want to be sure, as documentations says always little about what really happens inside.

I have 2 sparse matrices stored though Eigen. If I enable mkl from eigen, is it going to use MKL for sparse (I understand dense is OK, I just want to know if it applies to sparse too, as there are several formats and eigen uses its own) matrix multiplication too?

Related questions:

[Use Intel MKL Sparse BLAS extensions through C++ Eigen library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57872878/use-intel-mkl-sparse-blas-extensions-through-c-eigen-library)

[Mkl + Eigen vs Mkl Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77726949/mkl-eigen-vs-mkl-only)

Comment: I don't think they do, at least for simple matrix multiplications. The documentation lists [supported solver modules](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__PardisoSupport__Module.html), though. You can check pretty easy for yourself: Just remove all linker commands for MKL (`-lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core` etc.) while keeping the include paths and preprocessors (`-I"${MKLROOT}/include" -DEIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL`). If you get a linker error that it cannot find an MKL symbol, you know Eigen tried to call MKL.